# C++ vectors and pairs

Tags: c++, vector

I am implementing a function and here is the RME:

```
//EFFECTS: returns a summary of the dataset as (value, frequency) pairs 
// In the returned vector-of-vectors, the inner vector is a (value,frequency) pair. The outer vector contains many of these pairs. The pairs should be 
// sorted by value. 
// { 
// {1, 2}, 
// {2, 3}, 
// {17, 1} 
// } 
// 
// This means that the value 1 occurred twice, the value 2 occurred 3 times, 
// and the value 17 occurred once 

std::vector<std::vector<double> > summarize(std::vector<double> v);
```

The above code is the function I am implementing.
How do I approach this?

BY THE WAY, there is a sort function available that I will use to sort the numbers so ignore that part.

I created a new vector for a pair of (double(double), int(freq)) and then did a for loop to put values in it. But then tried to return it but it said it couldn't convert my vector to the type that the function is supposed to return.

Comment: just share the code you tried so far, don't be afraid !

Comment: Why are you using a double for the frequency?  And if this is supposed to be a vector of pairs, why isn't the return type std::vector< std::pair< double, size_t > > or something equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to keep your data structure relevant to the data you are trying to represent. You have used the word pair so many times in your question that this is screaming for pairs. You could use a vector of pairs like:

```
std::vector<std::pair<double,int>> summarize
```

Or even better, use a map if you have unique values:

```
std::map<double,int> freqMap
```

Comment: He must have unique values since it has a frequency. The return type should be `std::map <double, int>`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some pseudocode:

```
sorted_vector = sort(input_vector);
current_value = sorted_vector[0];
count = 0;
for each element in sorted_vector:
    if element == current_value:
        count = count + 1;
    else:
        output_vector.push_back(current_value, count);
        current_value = element;
        count = 1;
// push final pair
output_vector.push_back(current_value, count);
```

Answer (score 0):

The return type should be a map, mapping each `double` to its frequency.

Modern:

```
std::map<double, int>summarize(std::vector<double> v)
{
    std::map<double, int> ret;
    for (auto& i : v)
        ++ret[i];
    return ret;
}
```

Pre-C++11:

```
std::map<double, int>summarize(std::vector<double> v)
{
    std::map<double, int> ret;
    for (std::map<double,int>::iterator it = v.begin();
            it != v.end(); ++it)
        ++ret[*it];
    return ret;
}
```

If you really must return a vector of vectors, take the sensible `summarize` function above and write a wrapper that bastardizes the return type to the vector of vectors by traversing the map.